# How to prove this problem. Prove that if f is continuous at s and f(s)≠0 then there is δ>0 such that f(t)≠0 for all t such that s-δ<t<s+δ

Tags: calculus

Prove that if $f$ is continuous at $s$ and $f(s)≠0$, then there is $δ>0$ such that $f(t)≠0$ for all t such that $s-δ<t<s+δ$.

Comment: Please edit your Question to put the problem statement into a wider context.  Readers can better respond if you tell us more about where the difficulty arises, or what interests you in the problem.   A bare problem statement is harder to respond to because we don't know what you think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a continuous function $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ with $|f(s)|=a\neq 0$.

By the definition of continuous, $\exists~\delta>0$, such that
$$|f(x)-f(s)|<\frac{a}{2},\quad \forall~x\in (s-\delta,s+\delta),$$
that is
$$|f(x)|>\frac{a}{2},\quad \forall~x\in (s-\delta,s+\delta).$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.